# How to use Coffeescript utility-classes in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I use Coffeescript as scripting- and testing-language for my angular application.
CoffeeScript is capable of defining classes, which I want to use in my application.
I want to wrap JSON objects, as received from the server, into utility classes.

Let's say I have a page called 'dashboard', which displays objects, which are called boxes. So I have the following controller:

```
class DashboardCtrl
  constructor: ->
    @ctrlName = 'DashboardCtrl'
    @boxes = [
      new Box { id: '12344555', name: 'Box 1', rootId: 'box1_rootId' },
      new Box { id: '12344555', name: 'Box 2', rootId: 'box2_rootId' },
      new Box { id: '12344555', name: 'Box 3', rootId: 'box3_rootId' },
      new Box { id: '12344555', name: 'Box 4', rootId: 'box3_rootId' },
      new Box { id: '12344555', name: 'Box 5', rootId: 'box3_rootId' }
    ]

angular
  .module('dashboard')
  .controller 'DashboardCtrl', ['BoxAPI', DashboardCtrl]
```

which should use the utility-class 'Box':

```
class Box
  constructor: (info) ->
    {@id, @name, @rootId} = info
```

This is tested, by the following unit test:

```
'use strict'

describe 'DashboardCtrl', ->
  ctrl = undefined

  beforeEach module 'dashboard', 'idgApis', 'lib'

  beforeEach inject ($rootScope, $controller) ->
    ctrl = $controller 'DashboardCtrl'

  it 'should load some boxes from the server', ->
    someBox = new Box {id: '12344555', name: 'Box 1', rootId: 'box1_rootId'}
    expect(ctrl.boxes).toContain someBox
```

which results in this output:

```
  DashboardCtrl > should load some boxes from the server
        ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Box
            at /home/roman/workspace/idg-frontend/build/app/js/dashboard/dashboard-controller.js:9
            at DashboardCtrl (/home/roman/workspace/idg-frontend/build/app/js/dashboard/dashboard-controller.js:9)
            at invoke (/home/roman/workspace/idg-frontend/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4185)
            at instantiate (/home/roman/workspace/idg-frontend/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4193)
            at /home/roman/workspace/idg-frontend/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8462
            at /home/roman/workspace/idg-frontend/build/test/app/dashboard/dashboard-controller_test.js:14
            at invoke (/home/roman/workspace/idg-frontend/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4185)
            at workFn (/home/roman/workspace/idg-frontend/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2364)
            at /home/roman/workspace/idg-frontend/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js:126
            at /home/roman/workspace/idg-frontend/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js:171
            at http://localhost:9876/karma.js:185
            at http://localhost:9876/context.html:163
        undefined
        TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'ctrl.boxes')
            at /home/roman/workspace/idg-frontend/build/test/app/dashboard/dashboard-controller_test.js:23
            at /home/roman/workspace/idg-frontend/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js:126
            at /home/roman/workspace/idg-frontend/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js:171
            at http://localhost:9876/karma.js:185
            at http://localhost:9876/context.html:163
```

Is this possible in Angular? How do I make the utilities available? How to make it work?

Comment: Where do you require your script with the `Box` class?

Comment: I don't require the class - the question is how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First declare it in a module of yours, e.g. as a factory:

```
angular
  .module 'dashboard'
  .factory 'Box', ->
    class Box
      constructor: (info) ->
        {@id, @name, @rootId} = info
```

Then in your test you can inject it:

```
describe 'DashboardCtrl', ->
  Box = undefined

  beforeEach module 'dashboard'

  beforeEach inject ($injector) ->
    Box = $injector.get 'Box'
```

And now you can access it in your `it` blocks.

Comment: This results in this error:
    DashboardCtrl > should load some boxes from the server
        TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'info.id')
            at Box (/home/roman/workspace/idg-frontend/build/app/js/lib/box-factory.js:9)
           ...